# problem in ajaxx request when i click on button then nothing happen

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

hello every one please help me to solve this problem

js file code

```
$(document).on('click', '.retweet-it', function(){

    var comment    = $('.retweetMsg').val();


    $.post('http://localhost/tweet/core/ajax/retweet.php', {retweet:$tweet_id,user_id:$user_id,comment:comment}, function(){
        $('.retweet-popup').hide();
        $count++;
        $counter.text($count); 
        $button.removeClass('retweet').addClass('retweeted');
    });

});
```

retweet.php code

```
if(isset($_POST['showPopup']) && !empty($_POST['showPopup'])){

    $tid  = $_POST['showPopup'];
    $get_id    = $_POST['user_id'];
    $tweet      = $getFromU->getPopupTweet($tid);
    ?>
    <div class="retweet-popup">
  <div class="wrap5">
    <div class="retweet-popup-body-wrap">
    <div class="retweet-popup-heading">
        <h3>Retweet this to followers?</h3>
        <span><button class="close-retweet-popup"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
    </button></span>
    </div>
    <div class="retweet-popup-input">
        <div class="retweet-popup-input-inner">
            <input class="retweetMsg" type="text" placeholder="Add a comment.."/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="retweet-popup-inner-body">
        <div class="retweet-popup-inner-body-inner">
            <div class="retweet-popup-comment-wrap">
                 <div class="retweet-popup-comment-head">
                    <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL.$tweet->Pimg;?>"/>
                 </div>
                 <div class="retweet-popup-comment-right-wrap">
                     <div class="retweet-popup-comment-headline">
                        <a><?php echo $tweet->screnname;?> </a><span>‏@<?php echo $tweet->uname;?> <? 
                          php echo $tweet->postedon;?></span>
                     </div>
                     <div class="retweet-popup-comment-body">
                        <?php echo $tweet->status;?>  | <?php echo $tweet->timg;?>
                     </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="retweet-popup-footer"> 
        <div class="retweet-popup-footer-right">

            <button class="retweet-it"  type="submit"><i class="fa fa-retweet" aria-hidden="true"> 
            </i>Retweet</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div><!-- Retweet PopUp ends-->
    <?php
 }
?>
```

this is my whole code when i click on retweet-it class button then my ajax code is not work plese help me to solve this problem its most important for me . Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: how you execute javascript code with event handler? I mean the document is ready at this moment?

Comment: yes document is ready at that moment

Comment: What does the developer console of your browser say? What response do you get?

Please obey this from the jQuery documentation: If a request with jQuery.post() returns an error code, it will fail silently unless the script has also called the global .ajaxError() method. Alternatively, as of jQuery 1.5, the .error() method of the jqXHR object returned by jQuery.post() is also available for error handling.

Comment: no developer console can't show any error . i want if i click retweet-it class button then  simply retweet-popup class div is hide